# Best practices for Fragments + ViewBinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

From a Google Codelab (can't remember which one), they adviced doing the following for fragments:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: MyFragmentBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = MyFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

}
```

And then accessing the views with e.g. `binding.button1`.

Is there a specific reason for doing it like this, with *_binding* and *binding*? Are there better methods? Perhaps an extension for Fragments - like a BaseFragment - to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66751722/kotlin-lateinit-vs-computed-property) for some answers about the reason *why* binding needs to be nullable in a fragment.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72994918/506796) of mine where I linked some articles about the problems with BaseFragments. You can usually achieve the code reuse without the drawbacks of inheritance by using extension properties and functions.

[Here is an example](https://gist.github.com/Zhuinden/ea3189198938bd16c03db628e084a4fa#file-fragmentviewbindingdelegate-kt) of a property delegate that takes care of releasing the ViewBinding reference when necessary and rebuilding it when necessary. If you use this, all you need is a single binding property. Example is from [the article about this tool](https://zhuinden.medium.com/simple-one-liner-viewbinding-in-fragments-and-activities-with-kotlin-961430c6c07c).

```
class FirstFragment: Fragment(R.layout.first_fragment) {
  private val binding by viewBinding(FirstFragmentBinding::bind)

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, bundle: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, bundle)

    binding.buttonPressMe.onClick {
      showToast("Hello binding!")
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like that delegate! Do I still need to add any code inside onCreateView?

Comment: Sorry, my example was poor. Just updated it. This relies on using the layout ID in the constructor. Then you don't use `onCreateView()` at all. @shko

Comment: Perfect, this was exactly what I wanted. Great resources linked as well.

Comment: Btw, regarding `button.onClick`. Was that just pseudocode, I thought you had to write `setOnClickListener`?

Comment: Yes,  I assume so. I just copy-pasted from the linked article without noticing that.

Comment: I read through the comments on the gist, and it seems like the delegate caused some crashes. So I am considering sticking with the old approach just to be safe. Have you had any troubles with it yourself?

Comment: I've never bothered using it myself. I never have a need for using the binding outside `onViewCreated()` anyway, so I don't put the binding in a class level property. But from looking at the comments on the gist, it appears to be user error to me. Can't tell for sure without reviewing their code. My pattern is to use the `Fragment` constructor that takes a layout ID so I don't need to override `onCreateView`. Then in `onViewCreated()` I use `.bind(view)` to create the binding as a local variable. Frankly, I'm not sure what other people are doing that requires the binding to be in a property.

Comment: Maybe breaking out individual parts of their UI setup into individual functions instead of doing it all directly in `onViewCreated()`, which is what I typically do. Or they could be implementing interfaces directly with the Fragment instead of as anonymous objects, which I consider poor encapsulation and possibly fragile.

Comment: Yes, I tend to create several functions myself to avoid `onViewCreated` becoming messy. Thanks for the input on the library, I think I will skip it for now.

Answer (score 5):

It's not recommended to use BaseFragment or BaseActivity or BaseViewModel... it will just add boilerplate code to your project.

For binding you can just use it like this:

Declaration:

```
private var binding: MyFragmentBinding? = null
```

onCreateView:

```
binding = MyFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
binding?.root
```

Usage:

```
binding?.button...
binding?.text...
binding?.cardView...
```

onDestroyView:

```
binding = null
```

And everything is going to work just fine but we use the null check a lot (?) and it's making the code messy and we need to get a lot of null checks if we need something from a certain view, so we are sure that between `onCreateView` and `onDestroyView`, the binding is not null so we have `_binding` and `binding`:

```
private var _binding: MyFragmentBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!
```

We make `_binding` mutable with var so we can give it a value, and we make it nullable so we can clear it later.
And we have `binding` that have a custom getter so that means that each time we call `binding` it's going to return the latest value from `_binding` and force that it's not null with `!!`.

Now we seperate our variables, we have `_binding` to initialize and clear our binding, and we have `binding` that is immutable and not nullable to use it only for accessing views without null check `?`

Comment: So in essence, I should keep doing it like in the question?

Comment: Yes keep working like that, and add the code inside onViewCreated function not inside onCreateView

Comment: Wait, why use onViewCreated? I have been doing it like this forever without any problems.

Comment: Also, would it not be less boilerplate code if I had a BaseFragment?

Comment: This is from android documentation: It is recommended to only inflate the layout in onCreateView method and move logic that operates on the returned View to onViewCreated.

They recommend using onViewCreated because the view is totally created for sure there, but in onCreateView a lot of developers had problems and crashes. So use onCreateView just to inflate view.

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment?hl=en#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,android.view.ViewGroup,android.os.Bundle)

Comment: For BaseFragment you can't achieve it, the code that inflate the binding can't be moved to BaseFragment, try it and you will have a problem when you try to call .inflate inside the BaseFragment

Comment: Interestingly, the official Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments) and [samples](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/main/ViewBindingSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/viewbindingsample/InflateFragment.kt) use onCreateView, not onViewCreated.

Comment: It's the same but onViewCreated is safer, you can check the link in the android documentation they recommend using onViewCreated but in examples and sample they use onCreateView for simplicity

Comment: Ok got it. What do you think about the implementation in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74619674/14969444) below?

Comment: It's good in term of code, but he uses bind instead of inflate, I recommend using inflate because it's going to create the view faster.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that CommonsWare has adressed this issue in [this](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-fragments-007.html) post.

Here is the parent class:

```
abstract class ViewBindingFragment<Binding : ViewBinding>(
  private val bindingInflater: (LayoutInflater, ViewGroup?, Boolean) -> Binding
) : Fragment() {
  private var binding: Binding? = null

  override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
  ): View {
    return bindingInflater(inflater, container, false).apply { binding = this }.root
  }

  override fun onDestroyView() {
    binding = null

    super.onDestroyView()
  }

  protected fun requireBinding(): Binding = binding
    ?: throw IllegalStateException("You used the binding before onCreateView() or after onDestroyView()")

  protected fun useBinding(bindingUse: (Binding) -> Unit) {
    bindingUse(requireBinding())
  }
}
```

He then subclasses ViewBindingFragment like so:

```
class ListFragment :
  ViewBindingFragment<TodoRosterBinding>(TodoRosterBinding::inflate) {

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    useBinding { binding ->
      binding.items.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    }
  }
}
```

Though I am not sure it will eventually lead to less code, if `useBinding { binding -> }` needs to be called in several functions.

Comment: i think fragment should not have a constructor..? it would be a problem with their lifecycle